# How do you proof that F is a distribution function, when x > 0

Tags: probability, random-variables

I hope that someone could help me solve this question of my textbook:

```
Let F (x) = e^(−1/x) for x > 0 and F (x) = 0 for x ≤ 0. Is F a distribution
function? If so, find its density function.
```

How do you proof that F is a distribution function? Normaly I would make it equal to 1, but I don't know what I can fill in at the upper bound value of the integral, because the value is infinity.

The answer of the textbook is:

> Yes, $x^{−2}e^{−1/x} $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a (cumulative) distribution function precisely if

(1) $F$ is non-decreasing;

(2) $F$ is continuous from the right, that is, $\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x)=F(a)$ for all $a$;

(3) $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x)=0$;

(4) $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)=1$.

It is not difficult to see that your $F$ has the above properties.

**Remark:** In this case there is a density function, obtained by differentiating. That density function is not the one given in the OP. It is $0$ when $x\lt 0$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-1/x}$ when $x\gt 0$. If we feel like it we can say that the density function is $0$ at $0$.

Comment: I was trying to make it equal to 1. Thank you for help!

Comment: You are welcome. When $x$ is large positive, $F$ is near to $1$. We never get equality.